# Typo3 v10 - Content Elements in Extension Empty

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I have a typo3 extension which allows to create Content Elements within the extension - in typo3 v9 it works fine but on typo3 v10 it doesn’t, when I debug in the template i got this result:

```
contentElements => protected TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\LazyObjectStorageprototypeobject (empty)
```

The Content Element is created and in the backend also correctly visible within the Dataset

I also tried to have a look at tx_news which implements a simular behaiver but I doesn’t have a clue, for me it seems that I done right but yeah … , following some code snippets I used, may you have an Idea:

In the setup.typoscript:

```
lib.contenttabs_fecontenttabs.contentElementRendering = RECORDS
lib.contenttabs_fecontenttabs.contentElementRendering {
   tables = tt_content
   source.current = 1
   dontCheckPid = 1
}
```

In the Model (I tried to use the sam as news):

```
/**
 * Get content elements
 *
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage
 */
public function getContentElements()
{
    return $this->contentElements;
}

/**
 * Set content element list
 *
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $contentElements content elements
 */
public function setContentElements($contentElements)
{
    $this->contentElements = $contentElements;
}

/**
 * Adds a content element to the record
 *
 * @param \Moc\Contenttabs\Domain\Model\TtContent $contentElement
 */
public function addContentElement(\Moc\Contenttabs\Domain\Model\TtContent $contentElement)
{
    if ($this->getContentElements() === null) {
        $this->contentElements = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    }
    $this->contentElements->attach($contentElement);
}

/**
 * Get id list of content elements
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContentElementIdList()
{
    return $this->getIdOfContentElements();
}

/**
 * Get translated id list of content elements
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTranslatedContentElementIdList()
{
    return $this->getIdOfContentElements(false);
}

/**
 * Collect id list
 *
 * @param bool $original
 * @return string
 */
protected function getIdOfContentElements($original = true)
{
    $idList = [];
    $contentElements = $this->getContentElements();
    if ($contentElements) {
        foreach ($this->getContentElements() as $contentElement) {
            if ($contentElement->getColPos() >= 0) {
                $idList[] = $original ? $contentElement->getUid() : $contentElement->_getProperty('_localizedUid');
            }
        }
    }
    return implode(',', $idList);
}
```

In the Template:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.contenttabs_fecontenttabs.contentElementRendering">
    {tab.contentElementIdList}
</f:cObject>
```

Some of the TCA Code (which seems to works fine):

```
'content_elements' => [
          'exclude' => 1,
          'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
          'label' => 'Content Elements',
          'config' => [
             'type' => 'inline',
             'allowed' => 'tt_content',
             'foreign_table' => 'tt_content',
             'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting',
             'foreign_field' => 'tx_tabs_content_elements',
             'minitems' => 0,
             'maxitems' => 99,
            'overrideChildTca' => [
                'columns' => [
                    'colPos' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'default' => 99
                        ]
                    ],
                    'CType' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'default' => 'textmedia'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
             'appearance' => [
                'collapseAll' => 1,
                'expandSingle' => 1,
                'levelLinksPosition' => 'bottom',
                'useSortable' => 1,
                'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                'showRemovedLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1,
                'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                'enabledControls' => [
                   'info' => false,
                ]
             ]
          ]
        ],
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post your variable definition for $this->contentElements - since it might contain some deprceated stuff that has been replaced in CMS 10?

Comment: For sure here is the definition:
/**
* @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Moc\Contenttabs\Domain\Model\TtContent>
* @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\ORM\Lazy
*/
protected $contentElements;

/**
* __construct
*/
public function __construct()
{

//Do not remove the next line: It would break the functionality
$this->initStorageObjects();
$this->contentElements = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
}

Comment: Looks like a 1:1 copy of the news extension, so it should be working. I guess the propblem might be in your tt_content model then.